# DataReader open on a connection in a while loop despite being specifically closed

Tags: c#

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command
>   which must be closed first.

Okay. So. We do a LOT of database reading in this, enough to justify a generic function to simplify it. I've just changed it so the function no longer closes connections when called with an active one, since it's one line either way. In doing so, I found this bug. On the second iteration of the `while` loop, the DBRead function will get an error when trying to actually execute, complaining as per the above error.
However. At the end of each iteration, there's a reader.Close() call with no condition.

Now... I've done some looking around for this, and discovered something about using `using` with these... To be honest, I'm not sure how I would do that here (I could figure it out quickly enough, I guess), but moreover, I don't know if it would fix the problem.

Every other question I read was actually not closing. Whereas in this case, I *think* I'm calling one close for every open, on the readers, and then reusing the connection **after** that. How wrong am I?

```
        // Find all the unprocessed gifts in the inhouse table.
        SQL = "SELECT * FROM ToREgift WHERE processed = 0";
        ReadCommand.Connection = ReadConnect;
        ReadCommand.CommandText = SQL;
        dbRERead = ReadCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (dbRERead.Read())  // Loop through them.
        {
            RowId = Convert.ToInt32(dbRERead["id"].ToString());

            // Lookup the RE ConstituentId from the ToREConstituent table.
            string ToREConstituent_Id = dbRERead["ToREConstituent_id"].ToString();
            Reader = FunctionsClass.DBRead(vars.Catalog, "SELECT Constituent_Id FROM ToREConstituent WHERE ID = " + ToREConstituent_Id.ToString(), ref Connection);
            Reader.Read();
            string ConstituentId = Reader["Constituent_Id"].ToString();
            bool UseRG = false;
            try
            {
                UseRG = Convert.ToBoolean(dbRERead["Use_RG"]);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
            ;

            if (!UseRG)
            {
                if (dbRERead["TypeOfGift"].ToString() == "RecGiftPC")
                {
                    UseRG = true;
                }
            }

            AddSingleGift(ConstituentId, UseRG, RowId);

            SQL = "SELECT Constituent_Id FROM ToREConstituent WHERE Id = " + ToREConstituent_Id;
            dbRECommand.CommandText = SQL;
            Reader = dbRECommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (Reader.Read())
            {
                ConstituentId = Reader["Constituent_Id"].ToString();
            }
            Reader.Close();

        }
        dbRERead.Close();

--

public static SqlDataReader DBRead(string DB, string SQL, ref SqlConnection Connection)
{
    SqlDataReader functionReturnValue = null;
    // !! IMPORTANT !!
    // This will initialise and open a connection as needed.
    // The caller is responsible for closing the connection
    if(Connection==null)
    {
        Connection = new SqlConnection();
    }
    if(Connection.ConnectionString=="")
    {
        Connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source = REDEV;Initial Catalog = " + DB + ";Integrated Security = True";
    }
    try
    {
        Connection.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if(ex.Message!="The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.")
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        // Else continue, because if that's the error, doesn't matter, just move on.
    }
    SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand();

    dbCommand.Connection = Connection;
    dbCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    dbCommand.CommandText = SQL;
    dbCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;

    try {
        functionReturnValue = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();
        return functionReturnValue;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //frmMain.BatchError = true;
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error reading Database. Can't Continue, sorry. Debug information below:" + vars.vbCrLf + vars.vbCrLf + ex.Message + vars.vbCrLf + SQL + vars.vbCrLf + vars.vbCrLf + Connection.ConnectionString);
        Connection.Close();
        System.Environment.Exit(0);
    }

    return functionReturnValue;
    // Cleanup
    //dbCommand = Nothing

}
```

Comment: Please, do a **big** refactoring there and every single issue will disappear. Empty `catch` blocks, catching `Exception` and checking for exact localized message (ignoring everything else). No `using` at all. Create connection in one method and let it to be closed in another (without any using block) may be astonishing when someone else will read it. `vars.vbCrlf`? Why not `Environment.NewLine`? `while (reader.Read())` when you need just one record. SQL code built without parameters (what about SQL injection?). BTW where do you close connection?! You also do not dispose `DBCommand` in `DBRead`

Comment: Well, I guess a closer look will also find something else but **IMO** it's time to rewrite these few lines. Try with few simple rules: 1) When a class implements `IDisposable` then you must use `using`. 2) Do not catch `Exception` (unless you have a very very good reason) but exactly what you need. 3) Try to make your functions as small as possible (doing exactly one task, each one). 4) Do not concatenate strings to build SQL commands: use parameters.

Comment: I concur. The code in its current state is bad, bad, bad. Throw it out and start again.

Comment: Alright. I'm taking an entirely different approach to it now anyway, because we fixed it with a workaround (passing the reader into the DBRead function), and got back to the real issue, which is that temprecords was always empty for some reason. So, throwing it all out and doing something different. I'll still be trying to take into account the stuff you've suggested. Also, `Environment` doesn't always exist, whereas the `vars.VbCrLf` that we defined does. (Granted, it's not VB, but we started with code that we converted from. Haven't seen reason to change the name.)